# Jasmine return rejected in a mocked factory's promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

My controller's init:

```
    var init = function () {
        httpUsers.getUsers().then(function (data) {
            $timeout(function() {
                // Do something...
            });
        }).catch(function (error) {
            vm.error = "Me!";
            toastr.error(error);
        });
    }
```

My mocked service:

```
beforeEach(function() {
    module('httpService', function($provide) {
        $provide.factory('httpUsers', function () {

            var service = {
                getUsers: getUsers
            }

            function getUsers() {
                    deferred = $q.defer(); // deferred is a global variable
                    deferred.resolve([
                        { id: 1, firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe" },
                        { id: 2, firstName: "Jane", lastName: "Doe" },
                        { id: 3, firstName: "Jack", lastName: "Doe" }
                    ]);
                    return deferred.promise;
            };

            return service;
        });
    });
});
```

Everything works fine for returning the resolved promise.

However, I want to test the `catch` clause in my controller's init function.

I've tried this:

```
describe('init', function() {
    it('should throw error', function () {
        deferred.reject('testing');
        expect(controller.error).toBe("Error!");  // NOTE: 'vm' is set to 'this', so controller is 'vm'
    });
});
```

But all I get is:

`Expected undefined to be 'Error!'.`

I don't get 'testing', 'Me!', or 'Error!'.  How do I force a rejection on the promise from my test?

Thanks!

**EDIT**
Here's my controller injection:

```
beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _$rootScope_, _$q_, _$timeout_, _global_) {

    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
    $q = _$q_;
    $timeout = _$timeout_;
    global = _global_;

    controller = _$controller_('usersController', {
        $rootScope: $rootScope,
        $scope: $scope,
        $q: $q
    });

    $timeout.flush();
}));
```

Comment: try scope.$apply(); after you call deferred.reject. also make sure scope is injected properly.

Comment: I've already tried that and `$rootScope.$apply();` but neither worked.  FYI, I've updated the question so that you can see the controller injection.

Comment: Can you also try to move the deferred.resolve from the mock method to your test method? otherwise, the promise is always resolved when you call getUsers. What I usually do is just return a promise from mock service and then resolve it when I want to test resolved promise or reject it when I want to test rejection. I am not sure if I am clear enough...

Comment: How would I do this?

Comment: Please see the answer. make sure your test can access $scope and $timeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like below: -
Your mock service

```
beforeEach(function() {
    module('httpService', function($provide) {
        $provide.factory('httpUsers', function () {

            var service = {
                getUsers: getUsers
            }

            function getUsers() {
                deferred = $q.defer(); // deferred is a global variable
                return deferred.promise;
            };

            return service;
        });
    });
});
```

your test for rejection

```
describe('init', function() {
    it('should throw error', function () {
        deferred.reject('testing');
        $scope.$apply();
        expect(controller.error).toBe("Error!"); 
    });
});
```

your test for resolve

```
describe('init', function() {
    it('should throw error', function () {
        deferred.resolve([
                    { id: 1, firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe" },
                    { id: 2, firstName: "Jane", lastName: "Doe" },
                    { id: 3, firstName: "Jack", lastName: "Doe" }
                ]);
        $scope.$apply();
        $timeout.flush();
        expect(controller.error).toBe("Error!"); 
    });
});
```

Comment: that works.  I guess i was hoping to supply the data once for all of my tests and just have a "one off" scenario.  With this I have to create a global variable (inside of my main 'describe') to hold a list of users, then for each test I have to have `deferred.resolve(angular.copy(users));`  Is there a better way to reuse the array or have a default scenario?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: what about put it into a function? i.e. function resolvePromise(){deferred.resolve.....}. then in your test method, just call resolvePromise() or rejectPromise()

Comment: yeah, there's a couple of ways i could do it.  I'm new to jasmine, but I'm use to other mocking frameworks that allow you to create test setup fixtures that are run before every test, but you could override the 'default action' in the individual test if you needed to.  So, again, being able to have `deferred.resolve()` as the default, but override it in a "one off" test. oh well.

Comment: you could actually create 2 test suites, one has beforeEach that always resolve, while the other suite has beforeEach that always reject the promise. Well, as you said, there are many way to do it, so, pick up the one you like, :)